# how to create new bullent icon inside a div element according to no of div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to create bullet icon dynamically according to no of div.

for example if i have 2 div slider, so i want to create 2 bullet icon inside other div if div count is 0 bullet should be display none.

I want something like this

```
<div class="mainslider">
  <div class="slider"><img src="abc.jpg"></div>
  <div class="slider"><img src="xyz.jpg"></div>
</div>

<div class="bullet">
  <a href="#1">&bull;</a>
  <a href="#2">&bull;</a>
</div>
```

basically i want to create bullet icon dynamically according to no of slider div.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count how many `div` with "slider" `class` there are, then cycle this number to append new `a` with bullets to `div` with "bullet" class.

```js
$(function() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= $(".slider").size(); i++) {
    $("<a></a>").attr("href", "#" + i).html("&bull;").appendTo(".bullet");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainslider">
  <div class="slider">
    <img src="abc.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <img src="xyz.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bullet">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Alessio . It's very useful for me